# ScriptableObject.ctor and LoadAssetAtPath error in unity 5.4

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting these three errors each time i playing my scene. There error making no problem but i am unable to understand that why i am getting this.

**1**

> ScriptableObject.ctor is not allowed to be called from a ScriptableObject constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in OnEnable instead. Called from ScriptableObject 'Find_Object_by_component'.
>       See "Script Serialization" page in the Unity Manual for further details.
>       UnityEditor.SceneView:.ctor()
>       Find_Object_by_component:.ctor()

**2**

> LoadAssetAtPath is not allowed to be called from a ScriptableObject constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in OnEnable instead. Called from ScriptableObject 'Find_Object_by_component'.
>           See "Script Serialization" page in the Unity Manual for further details.
>           UnityEditor.SceneView:.ctor()
>           Find_Object_by_component:.ctor()

**3**

> UnityException: LoadAssetAtPath is not allowed to be called from a ScriptableObject constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in OnEnable instead. Called from ScriptableObject 'Find_Object_by_component'.
>       See "Script Serialization" page in the Unity Manual for further details.
>       UnityEditor.EditorGUIUtility.Load (System.String filename, System.Type type) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/EditorGUIUtilityBindings.gen.cs:470)
>       UnityEditor.EditorGUIUtility.Load (System.String path) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/EditorGUIUtilityBindings.gen.cs:464)
>       UnityEditor.EditorGUIUtility.LoadGeneratedIconOrNormalIcon (System.String name) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/EditorGUIUtilityBindings.gen.cs:182)
>       UnityEditor.EditorGUIUtility.LoadIconForSkin (System.String name, Int32 skinIndex) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/EditorGUIUtilityBindings.gen.cs:206)
>       UnityEditor.EditorGUIUtility.LoadIcon (System.String name) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/EditorGUIUtilityBindings.gen.cs:177)
>       UnityEditor.EditorGUIUtility.LoadIconRequired (System.String name) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/EditorGUIUtilityBindings.gen.cs:167)
>       UnityEditor.EditorGUIUtility.TextContentWithIcon (System.String textAndTooltip, System.String icon) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/EditorGUIUtilityBindings.gen.cs:117)
>       UnityEditor.EditorWindow.GetLocalizedTitleContentFromType (System.Type t) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorWindow.cs:119)
>       UnityEditor.EditorWindow.GetLocalizedTitleContent () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorWindow.cs:102)
>       UnityEditor.SceneView.OnEnable () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:350)
>       UnityEditor.SceneView:.ctor()
>       Find_Object_by_component:.ctor()

Answer (score 2):

A `ScriptableObject` constructor should not be used for anything, unless you know exactly what you're doing and why you need to break the rules. The reason is that `ScriptableObjects` aren't constructed in the main Unity thread, thus you can't really use the Unity API. (`Debug.Log` is one of the few Unity functions you can use in any thread.)

Use the `Awake` or `OnEnable` functions for initialization. If it's a `MonoBehaviour`, you can also use `Start`. These are called automatically by the game engine.

If you really can't find the offending class, you can use find/replace to change all the function calls from `AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath` to `MyDebugClass.LoadAssetAtPath`. Next, define:

```
#line hidden
public static class MyDebugClass
{
  public static Object LoadAssetAtPath(string assetPath, Type type)
  {
    Debug.Log("LoadAssetAtPath called: " + assetPath);
    return AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(assetPath, type);
  }
}
#line default
```

This hack will show you each caller, and the message directly before the error will point to the culprit. (Not an elegant technique, but it will give you a fast answer. Though I can't check the syntax at the moment.)

Note: `#line hidden` means this function won't show up in the stack trace. So the top line of your stack trace will be the line you're interested in, rather than a line inside `MyDebugClass`.

Comment: ok this is fine but where i am doing this? there is no custom script has found in the error?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan Good question! I don't see any filename. But you can do a search for `LoadAssetAtPath`, and open the files that are `ScriptableObject` and have a look in each. Or if you have a ton of files like that, you could do a full text search/replace so `LoadAssetAtPath` becomes `MyDebugScript.LoadAssetAtPath`, then define a static class/function with that name which prints a message whenever it's called. That will show the log in the call stack. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan Check the answer again to see a lazy technique to see which function call is causing the problem.